# RxJS Add an observable after subscribe

Tags: rxjs

Is there a way to add one more element after an observable has been subscribed?

```
observable = timer(1000,2000).take(5)
observable.subscribe()
//Now I want to add one more element to observable....
```

Comment: What do you mean? Observables are stream of events that you can observe. You don't "add" an element to an observable, unless it's a Subject. Or would you like to concatenate the observable with another one? Search for concat() in the documentation then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a subject is what you are looking for, a subject is both an observable and an observer.

```js
const { Subject, timer, fromEvent } = rxjs;
const { take } = rxjs.operators;

let subject$ = new Subject();

subject$.subscribe(val =>  { console.log(val); });

timer(1000,2000).pipe(take(5)).subscribe(val => { subject$.next(val); });

fromEvent(document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0], 'click').subscribe(() => {
  subject$.next('clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: Good idea to make simple rxjs answers run via cloudfare :). I will adapt it in the future.

Comment: There you go, I edited your answer to be runnable in a snippet for you.

Comment: Thank's for the effort!

Answer (score 1):

**You can use a combination of [merge](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html) and [Subjects](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/)**

```js
const { Subject, timer, merge } = rxjs;
const { take } = rxjs.operators;

let source_1 = timer(1000,2000).pipe(take(5));
let source_2 = new Subject();

let final_source = merge(
  source_1,
  source_2
);

final_source.subscribe(e => console.log(e));

source_2.next('jabadabadoo!');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```